# New php page forced out of iframe into whole window

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I am calling a new url from inside an iframe and want the new url to abandon the iframe (it can close / destroy it if necessary) and appear full screen.  The complication is that i do not have control of the call to the new php file becuase it is done by a credit card payment server as a redirect.

To clrify, I have a page called order3.php whihc has an iframe in it where the credit card action takes place.  At the end, I tell the credit card server that we want to now go to order4.php (but i can't tell it anything else such as script with this instruction, just the page name).  As one would expenct order4.php now appears in the ifrmae within order3.php.  What i want is for order4.php to declare independence as it loads and insist that it is full screen.

I am not being lazy and i have had a good look areound, but i cannot understand the posts that give a single line of javascript and say that that will work because i don't know where to put it!

I have tried this:

```
<script>document.location.replace('order4.php');</script>
```

in the header of order4.php, but needless to say it doesn't work.  It does cause the iframe to disappear, which is a start, but you then get a white area where the iframe was and order3.php is still showing.  Actually, the browser seems to get stuck in a loop at that point.

So in summary, what can i do to order4.php so that when it is displayed it forgets the past and just goes whole screen what ever anybody else says.

Please, be concise and tell me exctly where to put any code snippets you are kind enough to provide and please remeber that i cannot control the syntax of the call to order4.php.  I'm not sure, but i think that you may need to know that i have this in my header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Hi - has anybody got any ideas - would really appreciate some help with this.  Thanks...

Comment: Downvote????? You could at least comment to justify.  I know i am a novice and might have not have very much to contribute, but to just give me the finger without explanation is not cool!

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

Not sure if this was not picked up because it is tricky or simply beneath contempt, but here is the solution for anybody who wants it.

So Order3.php has the iframe and is the starting point.  The third party server is instructed to call an intermediate page which handles the closure of the iFrame and a redirect to order4.php rather than calling order4 directly.  So instead of going straight to the final target, go via a control URL within the iFrame which calls a function in the parent (the original order3.php)  to close the iframe and redirect the whole window to the eventual goal, order4.

1st declare the function that you are going to call within the head of the original php, order3.  I have an included .js file in my header so the code below goes in there, but you will need to enclose the code in script tags if you are going to just put it in the HTML head of order3.  Thinking about it, you could probably get away without closing the iFrame and just doing the replace, but this seems to work and it gets rid of any doubt.

```
function breaktoorder4() {
   window.frames[0].close();
   location.replace("https://www.website.co.uk/order4.php");
}
```

Next create the intermediate php (or html) that will be called within the iFrame.  I have called it breakframe.php.  Here is the whole page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="parent.breaktoorder4();">
</body>
</html>
```

Now tell the third party to point to breakframe.php rather than order4.php and hey presto, you should end up with order4 being shown in the whole window.

I have not tested this in all browsers, but it only uses very simple functions, so i can't think that there should be any problems.  Hope this helps.